# WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 12.05 and trying to connect to Windows Server 2012 for a database

My database name is 'jobs' and the ip address of the pc is 192.160.1.33 which is hosted in 1433

yet when I try to connect it gives the following error

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path
```

Please advise how to set that.

Comment: my favourite ubuntu version ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong jdbc driver and you're on Ubuntu 12.04 (there is no 12.05). Rather then hacking around with an old native driver for Windows (Linux libraries end in `.so` not `.dll`), I suggest you stop and use [this Type-4 one](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) from Microsoft. By definition, a type-4 driver uses no native libraries.

Comment: correct , thanks a lot, .dll can not be set in Ubuntu.